# How to get access to ancestors' attribute skipped for parent

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Let's say I have below hierarchy (pretty much simplified)

```
class Ancestor:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Ancestor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.a = 1
```

I don't want its `Child` to have access to `a` attribute

```
class Child(Ancestor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Ancestor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.b = 2
```

But I want its `Descendant` to have access both to `a` and `b`

```
class Descendant(Child):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Descendant, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there any way to get desired behavior and avoid multiple inheritance, e.g. `class Descendant(Ancestor, Child)`?

Comment: If you don't want access to `a` attribute then don't inherit from `Ancestor`. Create another class

Comment: @vishes_shell, It's not an option. I have to keep current structure

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a case for multiple inheritance. Child shouldn't inherit from Ancestor, but Descendant can inherit from both:

```
class Child:
    ...

class Descendant(Ancestor, Child):
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. Why, specifically?

Comment: Because of some weird restrictions on Project :) I'll get `-2` on code review if to apply multiple inheritance